# Grep not matching a simple pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I'm scratching my head on the following oversimplistic grep command:

```
grep "GMT \+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" gmt_funny.txt
```

where `gmt_funny.txt` contains:

```
2012-09-01 00:00:16.825 (GMT +02:00)
```

I've just discovered that the grep command doesn't match the line, unless I specify `-E` as follows:

```
grep -E "GMT \+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" gmt_funny.txt
```

Does this means grep doesn't handle extended regular expressions ? The man grep seems to indicate that `{` and `}` is not supported, shall be replaced by `\{` and `\}`. Is this correct?

If yes, is there an explanation to this misleading particular behaviour of grep?

Comment: Normally, grep uses BRE, you need flag to access ERE. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX `\{` and `\}` are BRE syntax, while `{` and `}` are ERE syntax.

Comment: Also, assuming ERE, your regex expects a literal `+` where there isn't one.

Comment: Instead of scratching your head, learn about `man`. `man grep` could've told you.

Comment: @nhahtdh Would you mind submitting this as an answer please ? ;)

Comment: For the "why" part, perhaps see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367415/874188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` uses [BRE syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_07), where quantifier syntax `\{m,n\}` requires backslash `\` on the curly brackets. So your first command can be changed to:

```
grep "GMT \+[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}" gmt_funny.txt
```

To use the [ERE syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04_08) in `grep`, where quantifier syntax is the familiar `{m,n}`, you need to specify [`-E` flag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) in your command, as you have found out in the question.