# Regex anchor \< versus \b for word boundary

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am learning regex. One of the problem requires me to find all words that begin with a vowel. I am using Python's `re` module for evaluating the regular expression.

Here is the regex I made:

```
\<[aeiouAEIOU].*?\>
```

The above regex does not work with the `\<` and the `\>` anchor but works with the `\b` anchor. Why?

Comment: I think different engines/flavors support different syntax for the same thing but I am not sure.

Comment: Well what is the text agains which you are trying to match, and can you include that in your question?

Comment: @VishalSingh "GNU" is not well-defined in this context. Some GNU utilities use `\<` ... `/>`, others use `\b`, others have no support at all for regex word boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does not work" is not correct; one works in some regex dialects, the other in others.

Most "modern" regex dialects (Python, Perl, Ruby, etc) use `\b` as the word boundary, on both sides.

More traditional regex dialects, like the original `egrep`, use `\<` as the left word boundary operator, and `\>` on the right.

(Strictly speaking, Al Aho's *original* `egrep` did not have word boundaries; this feature was added later. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367415/874188 for a one-minute summary of regex history.)

Comment: Just tried the regex in sublime text search and it worked. I am now curious to know why did the python code run. It should have thrown a warning. Anyways I learned something new: regex has different implementations

Answer (score 1):

Python `re` does not support "leading/starting word boundary" `\<` construct (in other regex flavors, also `\m` or `[[:<:]]`), nor the "closing/trailing word boundary", `\>` (in other regex flavors, also `\M` or `[[:>:]]`).

Note that leading and trailing word boundaries are not supported by most NFA, often referred to as "modern", regex engines. The usual way is to use `\b`, as you have already noticed, because it is more convenient.

However, this convenience comes with a price: `\b` is a context-depending pattern. This problem has been covered very broadly on SO, here is my answer  covering some aspects of `\b`, see [Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

So, if you plan to use `\<` or `\>`, you need to implement them manually like this:

- `\<` = a position at a word boundary where the char to the right is a word char, i.e. **`\b(?=\w)`**.
- `\>` = a position at a word boundary where the char to the left is a word char, i.e. **`\b(?<=\w)`**.

This is how these word boundary variants are handled in the [PCRE library](http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt):

> COMPATIBILITY FEATURE FOR WORD BOUNDARIES
>
> In  the POSIX.2 compliant library that was included in 4.4BSD Unix, the
> ugly syntax `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` is used for matching  "start  of  word"
> and "end of word". PCRE treats these items as follows:
>
> `[[:<:]]`  is converted to  `\b(?=\w)`
> `[[:>:]]`  is converted to  `\b(?<=\w)`